# Saving file locally and remotely in Aptana Studio

Tags: aptana

I have installed Aptana Studio 3 on my pcs (windows xp, windows vista) I set up an ftp connection and that seems to work fine. However, how do I save the files locally as well? I do not see an option for that. I had a problem with a file on the server and I didn't have a file to back it up - or at least I couldn't find it. When I set up Aptana Studio, I used default settings.
So I guess my question is: How do I set up to save files locally and remotely? Can they be saved locally and remotely simultaneously when you hit 'save'?

Thanks for any help.

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for similar functionality for a while now, and just submitted this feature request:

http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3143

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to set up a project, set up a FTP connection, and then set the option to "Sync files on save"

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP%2C+SFTP%2C+and+FTPS+Deployment

Comment: This is not ideal. Isn't there a way to setup backups for FTP connections without the extra work of setting up a Project?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any more overhead in setting up a project than creating a backup location would be. File > New > Web Project. Name it. Done. Now add your connection. If what you truly want is to only edit remotely, and save local copies as you are editing for backups (but that would only be what you edited), I suggest filing a feature request.

Comment: What I want it to actually do is auto-create folders (based off the FTP connection), and then create incremental backups inside of those folders.

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1

You must to set this option your folder from Aptana.
Click with left side button over the folder, so:
 "Publish -> Run Web Deployment Wizard... -> FTP/SFTP/FTPS"
 check "Automatically sync changes with the remote site"
 and check "Automatically sync from my machine to the remote site"